# Erro ao lançar app e menu "Run As" sem opções

Tags: android, eclipse

Tenho uma aplicação, o código não tem erro, mas eu não vejo a opção de selecionar o emulador , veja a imagem, estou tendo esta mensagem:

> The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recente launches

Como configurar corretamente?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é uma resposta, mas recomendo muito usar o Android Studio para desenvolver, é mantido pela Google, atualização e suporte constantes, funcionalidades para desenvolvimento como design de telas e etc... Acredito que hoje muito pouca gente ainda use o Eclipse ou o Intelij(que é base pro Android Studio) para desenvolvimento Android.

Answer (score 2):

São duas as razões para não aparecer nenhuma opção para lançar a aplicação:

- A primeira, na zona *"launch history*", porque a aplicação nunca foi executada.
- A segunda, no menu *"Run as"*, porque não está seleccionado nenhum projecto na lista do lado esquerdo. Esta é também a razão do erro.

Seleccione a pasta do projecto e as opções do menu *"Run as"* aparecerão.
Ou clique com o botão direito na pasta do projecto e escolha aí *"Run as"*.

Poderá também usar a opção *"Run Configurations..."* para criar uma configuração e, após criá-la, executar a aplicação.